# Best way to get the DDL Scripts of a Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to get the DDL Scripts of all the objects in a DB in SQL Server 2012.
I tried to use SSMS (Generate Scripts) option it is running more than an hour looks like it is not responding.

The below is the count of objects

```
type_desc   ObjectCount
DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT  1163
FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT  48
INTERNAL_TABLE  38
PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT  673
SEQUENCE_OBJECT 762
SERVICE_QUEUE   3
SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION    23
SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION 162
SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE    4069
SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION   65
SQL_TRIGGER 50
SYSTEM_TABLE    67
TYPE_TABLE  13
UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT   8
USER_TABLE  705
VIEW    258
```

I am not sure what is the best way to quickly get the DB Scripts. My DB is hosted online. I am connecting through SSMS client and I don't have access to DB Server.

Comment: You could also try the [Database Administrators forum](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Review your "generate script" options - probably you are trying to script all data. Besides 4K sps could take some time to be delivered on your host.

Comment: I checked Schema only in the Advanced Option

Comment: Where are you sending generated output to? (clipboard,file,query)